# How to concatenate array of chars into single string?

Tags: c, cs50

I have created a function that inputs a user's name and outputs their initials. For example, "John Doe" should be JD, and "Rick Dixon Lightning" should be RDL. It should even handle messy entries, such as "   geoRge 6w bu7sh," returning "GWB."

This code below functions perfectly, yet for one issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Your name: ");
    string name = GetString();
    int nameLength = strlen(name);

    int initials[nameLength];

    int initialSwitch = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nameLength; i++)
    {
        if(initialSwitch%2 == 0 && (int)name[i] != 32 && tolower(name[i]) >= 97 && tolower(name[i])<=122)
        {
            initials[initialSwitch] = (int)name[i];
            initialSwitch++;
        } else if(initialSwitch%2!=0 && (int)name[i] == 32){
            initialSwitch++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<initialSwitch; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",toupper(initials[i]));
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

The bottom output loop outputs each initial individually, whereas I need to output the initials as a single, concatenated string. I have scoured the internet and come up with my best solution, which unfortunately does not function properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Your name: ");
    string name = GetString();
    int nameLength = strlen(name);

    char initials[nameLength];

    int initialSwitch = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nameLength; i++)
    {
        if(initialSwitch%2 == 0 && (int)name[i] != 32 && tolower(name[i]) >= 97 && tolower(name[i])<=122)
        {
            initials[initialSwitch] = (int)name[i];
            initialSwitch++;
        } else if(initialSwitch%2!=0 && (int)name[i] == 32){
            initialSwitch++;
        }
    }

    initials[initialSwitch]=(int)"\0";

    for (int i = 0; i<initialSwitch; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",initials);
    }
}
```

For the test input "John Bill Doe," my attempted solution outputs "j\nj\nj\nj\nj\n," or five "j"s, each on their own line.

What am I getting wrong here?

EDIT:

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Do you know that the `\n` in the `printf` format string is for?

Comment: As a matter of style, when referring to character constants, use the single quote format rather than magic numbers e.g. `if(initialSwitch%2!=0 && (int)name[i] == ' ')`. 32 -> ' ', 97 -> 'a', 122 -> 'z'

Comment: `initials[initialSwitch]=/* null character attempt */;` is a corner problem as `initialSwitch` may equal `nameLength`.  Better to use `char initials[nameLength+1];`

Comment: `else if(initialSwitch%2!=0 && (int)name[i] == 32){
            initialSwitch++;` is incorrect as `initials[initialSwitch /* prior to the increment */]` is left unassigned.

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question. The right thing to do would be to write an answer explaining how you resolved the problem (you are allowed to answer your own questions). Then after a short time delay, you'll be allowed to accept your own answer.

Comment: @chux, my initialSwitch was assigned a value of 0 on line 14 just before the loop.

Comment: @JeremyP I have moved my answer from the question to an answer

Comment: @FinesseUpscale It is not the value of `initialSwitch` that is the issue, but of  `initials[initialSwitch /* prior to the increment */]` that was left dangling.  The `initials[initialCount]`, below, remedies that.

Comment: Great, at some point you should be able to accept the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone. To summarize, I made the following errors:

1. extraneous (int) declarations
2. looped over printing the string
3. had to create additional variable to store the count of initials
   I have added since my initial switch was including blanks in my
   initials array. This didn't show up in my top "working" example
   since they were blanks, so it was hard to debug that without being
   aware of the error.

Working code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Your name: ");
    string name = GetString();
    int nameLength = strlen(name);

    char initials[nameLength];

    int initialSwitch = 0;
    int initialCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nameLength; i++)
    {
        if(initialSwitch%2 == 0 && name[i] != 32 && tolower(name[i]) >= 97 && tolower(name[i])<=122)
        {
            initials[initialCount] = toupper(name[i]);
            initialSwitch++;
            initialCount++;
        } else if(initialSwitch%2!=0 && name[i] == 32){
            initialSwitch++;
        }
    }

    initials[initialCount]='\0';

        printf("%s\n",initials);

}
```

Comment: `char initials[nameLength];` is still too small, by 1.  Consider input of `"X"`.  Code will attempt `char initials[1]; ... initials[1]='\0';`.

Comment: `name[i] != 32 && tolower(name[i]) >= 97 && tolower(name[i])<=122` is more understandable as `name[i] != ' ' && tolower(name[i]) >= 'a' && tolower(name[i])<='z'`.  IAC, `islower((unsigned char) name[i])` can replace all that.  Yet I think code still has logic issues.